# How to run EMGU CV sample Application on Raspberry PI 2

Tags: c#-4.0, mono, raspberry-pi2

i had download the Emgucv for Raspberry Pi 2 and in that there some sample projects when iam trying to run the application using this cmd

```
 mono /home/pi/Downloads/libEmgu/usr/bin/Example.HelloWorld.monoexe
```

iam getting an exception

```
 Unhandled Exception:
 System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Emgu.CV.CvInvoke ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Emgu.Util.Platform --->      System.DllNotFoundException: c
 at (wrapper managed-to-native) Emgu.Util.Platform:uname (intptr)
 at Emgu.Util.Platform..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.GetModuleFormatString () [0x00000] in <filename  unknown>:0 
 at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at HelloWorld.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Emgu.CV.CvInvoke ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Emgu.Util.Platform ---> System.DllNotFoundException: c
at (wrapper managed-to-native) Emgu.Util.Platform:uname (intptr)
at Emgu.Util.Platform..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.GetModuleFormatString () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at HelloWorld.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

can any one help to guide how to run application using opencv.

Answer (score 0):

#### System.DllNotFoundException:

The Emgu CV native library is not begin found:

> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for Emgu.CV.CvInvoke --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for Emgu.Util.Platform --->
>   System.DllNotFoundException:

After you have installed & compiled Emgv CV (not just the C# wrapper code, but also the CPP code), on Linux you need to tell the `Mono` runtime where it can find the native libraries (EVEN if they are in the same directory as the C# assemblies):

### Running the Examples

```
cd bin
```

In your case:

```
cd /home/pi/Downloads/libEmgu/usr/bin/
```

### Assign the dynamic library path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

### Run the example within the bin dir:

```
mono Example.HelloWorld.monoexe
```

Reference the following link for more details: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Build_the_binary

Comment: i had download emgucv from https://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/?source=typ_redirect  and i followed all your steps but still iam getting same exception.

Comment: The link that you supplied is for OS-X, for RaspberryPI you need to build it yourself, use the link that I have in the answer and start at the Linux section and proceed from there step by step (there are R-Pi options included) and you should be good : http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Linux

Comment: it still havent worked for still iam getting the same error.:( :(